How would you say "He dialed a random number on a telephone five thousand times." in Latin?
Gary Kleck, in his famous study which attempts to estimate the frequency of defensive gun uses, dialed a random number on a telephone 5'000 times. I tried saying that in my video in the Latin language, like this:

Is quinque milia tempora diligit fortuitum numerum in telephone...

Is that correct?

Why the downvotes?

There's only one vote down at the moment, and I can only offer a guess for its rationale: Perhaps someone felt that you are inappropriately pushing an agenda on this site by linking to a video where you try to make a controversial point. You seem to have a habit of including in some way opinions that are irrelevant to your actual question, and that easily irritates people. Why include the link in this question? Granted, I didn't follow the link so I have no clue what it's about.

Note that there are important differences between dialing a random number on a telephone, dialing a random telephone number, and randomly dialing telephone numbers, and they will not produce the same distributions.

No, it's not correct.
Some issues:

That is not how you should be translating "time".
For example, "three times" is ter instead of tria tempora.
The relevant kind of numerals are covered in grammars, such as Allen & Greenough.
If you need "time" as in "first time", see this question.

The word for "telephone" that I've seen used is telephonum, of which your telephone is not a form.

Instead of recasting "dialed" as "chose numbers on telephone", it would probably be more direct to say "called".
I've seen the verb telephonare used for calling.
As we are clearly in a modern context here, I would not shy away from using natural derivatives.

The imperfect tense is probably a better fit than the perfect tense, but it depends on the context.

Depending on context, the pronoun is is not needed.
If there's no specific context but you want an explicit pronoun, I'd go with ille instead.


With these in mind, I'd recommend this instead:

Quinquies milies fortuito telephonabat.

Whether that's the optimal translation and whether it works in your context is for you do judge, but at least it strikes me as far easier to follow.

This is terrific, thanks! You don't comment on choice of "fortuito". Does your sentence convey the sense that each number chosen is random? Rather than he flipped one coin: heads dial 5000 numbers, tails go for a picnic. And is the notion of randomness as opposed to fortune better captured by a word derived from "alea"?

@Laska The Romans didn't have the modern concept of random, so we'll have to go with a less technical word that conveys the idea well enough. I'm not sure the word choice is perfect in that respect, but I think it works. If you want to look for better options in a dictionary, start with coming up with English words that would fit the bill, such as "haphazardly" or "aimlessly".

I totally respect your scholarship. Really I’m asking two questions. (1) Often when I transliterated Latin at school I found that there several ways one could stick the English words together to give a meaning. How does one convey a precise sense here that each number is chosen separately? (2) “Alea iacta est” suggests that the Romans did have a sense of randomness not too far from our own. We have a word “aleatory” - does that derive from a Latin word?

@Laska Better ask a follow-up question or wait for someone else to answer this one from another point of view. My point here was just to offer improvements to the proposed translation, not to go deep into any specific component.

Thanks, I'll leave it. You had given detailed comments on all the other parts of the sentence, but not covered "fortuito".  I see https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=aleatory offers "aleatorius" = "pertaining to a gamester".

For "a random number" or "at random", I suggest the phrase sine delectu (variant spelling dilectu). It means "without exercising deliberate choice," i.e., "indiscriminately."
Petrarch, De Sui Ignorantia:

[invidia] pharetrata fere quidem in aciem descendit, sagittis
aggreditur, e longinquo ferit. Hoc boni habet: ceca est, ut facile
declinetur, si provisa sit, et sine delectu iaciens sepe suos
vulneret.
Armed with a quiver, envy generally takes the field, firing its arrows
and striking from afar. But here's a good thing. Envy is blind, and
you can easily avoid it if you see it coming. It shoots its arrows
aimlessly, and often wounds its own troops. (trans. David Marsh)

Fronto, Ad Amicos Epistulae 2.8.1

Eo fit, ut ad me decurrant plurimi, qui tuam gratiam cupiunt. Quos ego
non temere
nec sine delectu audio, sed probe petentibus suffragium meum impertio.
Consequently very many who desire your favour have recourse to me. I
do not give them a hearing at haphazard and without circumspection,
but I lend my support to those whose petition is honest. (trans. C. R. Haines)

Seneca the Younger, Dialogues 11.2

Hoc ergo unum excogitasti quomodo maxime illi posses nocere; quo
melior est enim quisque, hoc saepius ferre te consueuit sine ullo
dilectu furentem et inter ipsa beneficia metuendam.
This, then, was the only means you could devise of doing him a great
injury. The better a man is, the more frequently he is wont to suffer
from your indiscriminate rage, you who are to be feared even when
you are bestowing benefits upon one. (trans. Aubrey Stewart)


My first thought when I read the question was to use temere, which is found in the Fronto passage. In fact, are you sure that 'at haphazard' is translating sine delectu and not temere?

@cnread Either way, that would also be a good word to record in an answer. I didn't touch upon the random aspect in my answer, but I'm happy to see takes on it.

@cnread yeah, if the translation follows the order of the original, "temere" = "at haphazard" and "sine delectu" = "without circumspection", but my opinion is that it works better the other way. The terms are similar, both conveying acting without sufficient thought, but temere is usually opposed to sufficient deliberation, whereas sine delectu is opposed to sufficient discrimination. I think the Petrarch example is particularly good, since firing arrows without selecting a specific target is very similar to dialing phone numbers without selecting a specific receiver.

@cnread I added a third example. But, as you might suspect, the very next sentence contains a similar sentiment, this time expressed with temere: Quantulum erat tibi immunem ab hac iniuria praestare eum hominem in quem uidebatur indulgentia tua ratione certa peruenisse et non ex tuo more temere incidisse!'
